# how to change the background of the Inputfield

Tags: inputfield

I am using 12.1, in the documentation, it says I can change the background of the `InputField`. I have tried `InputField[x,Background->Blue]`, but the InputField background is still white. Any suggestions on how to change the background color of the `InputField`?

Comment: What OS are you on? Works for me on Win10 and for WolframCloud as well.

Comment: I am using mac Catlina 10.15.7

Comment: WolframCloud also worked for me, but not on my desktop...